# Is it possible to fetch data from a server component using a client component in NextJs

Tags: javascript, next.js

I appologise for the way the question is phrased.
I have this server component called auth.ts that retrieves some user details after they’ve logged in.
This is my server side component //auth.ts

```
export const validateRequest = cache(
  async (): Promise<
    { user: LuciaUser; session: Session } | { user: null; session: null } > => {
    await dbConnect();
    const sessionId = cookies().get(lucia.sessionCookieName)?.value ?? null;
    if (!sessionId) {
      return {
        user: null,
        session: null,
      };
    }

    const result = await lucia.validateSession(sessionId);

    if (!result) {
      return {
        user: null,
        session: null,
      };
    }

    const profileAttributes = await getProfileAttributes(result.user);

    if (!profileAttributes) {
      return {
        user: null,
        session: null,
      };
    }
    result.user.profile = {
      ...profileAttributes,
      //We return "id" instead of "_id" to be consistent with
      //the way lucia returns the user object.
      //aternatively, don't return profile id at all
      //depending on the requirements of the app
      _id: undefined,
      id: profileAttributes._id,
    };

    try {
      if (result.session && result.session.fresh) {
        const sessionCookie = lucia.createSessionCookie(result.session.id);
        cookies().set(
          sessionCookie.name,
          sessionCookie.value,
          sessionCookie.attributes
        );
      }
      if (!result.session) {
        const sessionCookie = lucia.createBlankSessionCookie();
        cookies().set(
          sessionCookie.name,
          sessionCookie.value,
          sessionCookie.attributes
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error message', error);
    }
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
  }
);
```

Trying to retrieve the data in a server component seems straightforward, I did something like this

```
export default async function Home() {
  const { user } = await validateRequest();
return(

<>
{user? (
<h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
   Welcome, {user?.profile?.firstName}!
</h2> ):(
<>
<Link href="/auth/login">
 Go to Login
 <LogIn />
 </Link>
</>

)
}

</>
```

Tried to apply the same logic in a client component and all hell broke loose, I’ve been struggling to find a solution for a long time.

Please can someone explain what to do so that I can learn and take note of it for future references. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Call that api in layout.ts file and as the user information gets fetched, store that information in store i.e Redux or Zustand then you can get that data in any component and if that component is directly present in layout like navbar or footer then u do not need any store, u can directly pass the data into that component from layout.ts